# Яндекс убегает из iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Есть web приложение, в котором хочется иметь встроенный браузер. Добавил iframe и несколько флагов. Но например яндекс видит iframe и пытается открыть новое окно навигатора. Как можно не дать сайту обнаружить iframe?

Есть возможность инжектить js через расширение. Сейчас инжектится такой скрипт:

```
var badTargets = ["_blank", "__blank", "blank", "_new", "new", "_newtab", "newtab", "_hplink"];
var badRels = ["external", "ext", "e"];
var filterForms = true;
var newTarget = "main-frame";

function rewriteTarget(node) {
        if (!filterForms && (node.tagName == "FORM")) {
            return;
        }
        if (badTargets.indexOf(node.getAttribute("target")) != -1) {
            node.setAttribute("target", newTarget);
        }
        if (badRels.indexOf(node.getAttribute("rel")) != -1) {
            node.setAttribute("rel", "");
            node.setAttribute("target", newTarget);
        }
}
const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            if (mutation.target.tagName == "A") rewriteTarget(mutation.target);
            if (mutation.target.tagName == "FORM") rewriteTarget(mutation.target);
        }
    }
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document, config);
```

Но похоже не срабатывает.

Comment: **Есть возможность инжектить js через расширение.** что вы имеете в виду? свое расширение или userscript?

Comment: да, любое расширение

Comment: Ну я вижу два варианта. Первый вариант: вырезать из отображения все скрипты или для определенных скриптов описать свою песочницу в отдельных WebWorker. `iframe`, по всей видимости, будет не очень юзабилен, потому я предлагаю его заменить на `div`. Второй вариант: пересобрать браузер на WebAsm используя EcmaScripten, тогда вместо `iframe` будет `canvas`.

Comment: это не очень подходит потому как вэб приложению нужен ДОМ, а рендерить на канвасе не производительно

Comment: Ну и третий вариант - использовать отдельные окна, минус в том, что у окна есть заголовок, и с окном можно попытаться эмулировать интеграцию в web-страницу, но всё это будет выглядеть синтетически. Времена Java-апплетов и Flash давно позади, в современном web у всего открывается либо отдельное маленькое окно, либо (что чаще) своя вкладка.

Comment: вкладка и окно не пойдут потому как перекроют навигацию вэб приложения и без ctrl+w в основное окно не вернуться

Comment: В любом случае [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webviewTag/) в статусе deprecated в пользу PWA. Сейчас все расширения для браузера могут иметь только свою вкладку, свою кнопку на панели расширений и своё меню (в меню пока можно вставлять html-верстку, но и это в ближайшие годы прикроют). Пока аналог webview browser-view можно использовать в [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-view). А так в любом случае для этого придется форкать, пилить "свой браузер". Вопрос лишь в том на какого класса платформе js или c/cpp? Но вероятность фиаско 90%

Comment: у меня нет webview, начал сразу с pwa. потому и iframe + расширения.

Comment: возможно в новом хроме урезали доступ с расширений во фреймы, от того такой фокус и не получился. поищу флаг или откачу хром на пару версий пока

Comment: По поводу canvas мне кажется, в том случае не будет никакого ущерба производительности. Пока работает браузер внутри WebAsm, внешний браузер отдыхает. Если не считать чуть более завышенный аппетит к RAM, при достаточном количестве RAM производительность не должна пострадать. Этот путь на мой взгляд самый правильный и самый сложный.

Comment: А по поводу отдельных окон... ну да, заголовок чутка отъест полезного экранного места. Но на навигация пока полностью подвластна расширениям. Все hotkeys, переключения вкладок, перетаскивания окна, курсор, в общем, всё можно отслеживать. Можно двигать/ресайзить окна за основным окном, при уходе с вкладки можно скрыть окно. Согласен, что выглядит это немного странно, как, например, использование `alert()` или `prompt()`. Но все же вариант. И кстати говоря, Electron тоже собирает свой кусок пирога среди PWA. Рассматривать как вариант вполне можно. Там по вашей теме - полная свобода действий.

Comment: отдельное окно не вариант потому при клике за окном мы его теряем и достать обратно не получится потому как основная прога в фулскрине. на электрон надо много чего портировать сначала из обвеса. возможно стоит двигать в его сторону.

Comment: Ну смотрите, во-первых, событие клика можно отменить с помощью `preventDefault()`, во-вторых, даже если окно ушло вниз, его можно снова поднять на передний план. А по Electron вот есть очень короткий [список проектов](https://www.electronjs.org/apps?q=Browser), которые можно использовать за основу своего. Среди этих проектов есть браузеры на основе браузера и от Mozilla, от Microsoft, от Google. А если поискать на Github и других хостингах проектов, можно найти тысячи подобных проектов. Electron пока работает только на десктопе, но он и двигается в сторону Android. Один код на все платформы.